# Using Neos Server to submit GAMS file

Tags: gams, neos

When I submit a GAMS file along with a GDX file to the Neos Server upon clicking the submit button I don't get any error but the following webpage which is not loading and nothing is displayed. I checked the queue but my submission is not there either although no error message is displayed. I did not receive an email either. Can someone explain what to do about this?
[image]

Comment: Are you using this form?, https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/lp:CPLEX/GAMS.html - in addition to signing up you need other info besides the GDX file.

Comment: Yes, that is the form I am using. Do you mean I need other files? But those seem to be optional. When I run the gams file on my computer the error is that the data limit for the demo version is exceeded, which is why I am using Neos.

Comment: I can easily run other GAMS files that I can also run locally but in this case the only error message when I run locally is that the data limit for the demo version is exceeded but still I cannot run it on NEOS and there is no indication of why. If there were any syntax or other errors when I tried to run it locally an error message would be displayed.

Comment: Support questions for other sites are best asked with their Feedback Form, but I suspect that even though the other fields are optional you still need the email field in addition to the minimum (the upload of the program).